# How to use `wait` and `WSTOPPED` with bash?

Tags: git, bash

Suppose a parent process spawns several child processes, which at some point STOP themselves (not terminated yet). I want the parent to `wait` for all its children to be stopped, so they can work in lockstep.

This may be an XY Problem, so if there's a better way, I'm all ears. :)

I want to build a collaborative git mergetool for conflicts.

I have a parent process which spawns a child process for each conflicting file. The piece I am missing is "wait for all children to be stopped". How can I do this?

```
#parent.sh
# For each file in conflicting state
for f in `git ls-files --unmerged | cut -f2 | sort -u`
do
  git mergetool --tool=collaborate --no-prompt "$f" &
done

# Wait for all children to be STOPPED
wait # WSTOPPED? Not sure how to do this.

echo "All files uploaded. Visit www.example.com/abc123 to collaborate."
read -rsp $'Press enter to apply changes.\n'

# Continue all child processes.
kill -SIGCONT childpids? Need a list...

wait
echo "Finished!"
```

The child processes must work in lockstep.

```
#collaborate-mergetool.sh
BASE=$1
LOCAL=$2
REMOTE=$3
MERGED=$4

# TODO curl POST files to server

# When the four files are uploaded:
#   STOP this process and wait for siblings.
kill -SIGSTOP $$

# Download patch from server
# TODO curl GET "$filename".patch from server

# TODO apply patch
```

Comment: The `wait` built-in is extremely limited. In particular, it doesn't allow waiting for children to be STOPped. It seems like you actually need to build a semaphore utility, which I suppose you could do in bash using the `flock` utility (part of the util-linux package and not necessarily installed in all distros).

Comment: Thank you, flock looks like a good start, but I'm not too keen on the distro support. I see some recommendations to use `mkdir` as a lock. I could try that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```bsh
# instead of using wait, poll all child processes and detect those in a stopped state
while true ; do
  sleep 1
  N_CHILDREN=`jobs | wc -l`
  N_STOPPED=`jobs -s | wc -l`
  [ $N_CHILDREN == $N_STOPPED ] && break
done
```

Using shell sleep you are restricted to polling at a granularity of one second.

If you have other child processes that you don't want to wait for you will need to get more creative and parse the output of the jobs built-in:

```
STOPPED_JOBS_PIDS=`jobs -sl | awk '{print $2}'`
# Compare to my list, etc...
```

In some cases this may interfere with the operation of the shell itself.

In which case you will probably need to poll the output of ps instead:

```
...
# Get the 'stat' column and look for a T, filter by my child processes of interest
git mergetool ... & PID1=$!
git mergetool ... & PID2=$!  # etc
...
while ...
  N_CHILDREN=2 # number of processes
  N_STOPPED=`ps -o pid -o stat -p PID1 $PID2 | tail -n +2 | awk '{print $2}' | grep T | wc -l`
...
```

Here, the STAT column indicates whether the process is running (R), sleeping (S) or stopped (T) or a zombie or other states.

Comment: Does the output of ps vary based on os and user config?

Comment: To collect all my pids, I can do `pids=""` before my for loop, then `pids="$pids $!"` inside the loop. I now have a space-separated list of pids. I think I can make that work.

Comment: After collecting $pids, this works fine: `ps -ostat -p $pids | tail -n+2 | grep -v T`. Thanks for the help. It looks like simple polling will be fine for my application. The flock solution would require a bit of work.